# asp.net saving control values on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, textbox, postback

I have a dynamic table with some textboxes (also dynamic) and some buttons which do postback onclick.
How can I make the page remember what text was entered in the boxes after postback, after clicking a button?

Comment: can you show what you've tried ? or some code at least? its hard to help like this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create controls in a tymer click event.For that Create a new user control. Add public Properties in it for adding how much controls u have to add. And in Web user control Page INit and Page_load event Add the required number of controls. Hope this will work.

```
 //IN web user control aspx page add a place holder in which u add your dynamic    controls
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs"   Inherits="WebUserControl" %>


  <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"  ID="mycontrol"/>

  // WEb User Control Code Behind 

  // Create public properties

   public int totalnoOfcontrols
   {
    get;
    set;
   }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (IsPostBack)
    { 
        // save values here 
    }
 }
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
    // create dynamic controls here
     TextBox t = new TextBox();
    t.Text = "";
    t.ID = "myTxt";
    mycontrol.Controls.Add(t);
 }
```

Comment: Not sure how that would work since all the work is done in a Timer_Tick method.

Comment: u means controls are created on a tymer tick event ?

Comment: Yes because the amount of controls created is based on some calculation and the timer is there for the updateProgress to work

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Page_Init/Load` event handler to create controls runtime (*dynamically*).

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use the ViewState

```
string data = ViewState["myData"];

ViewState["myData"] = data;
```